# How do I use integrated graphics with ANGLE on MacOS?

Tags: macos, graphics, opengl-es, gpu, google-angle

How do I use integrated graphics with ANGLE on MacOS?

I have a program that renders with https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle (ANGLE) and can run on MacOS, and I was wondering how I could use the integrated graphics card instead of the discrete graphics card, I have already tried setting NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching to true, but it makes my view go away and still uses the graphics card somehow.

Is there some way that I can force it to use the integrated GPU if available because I think that using the graphics card is overkill for my application?